# In NetSuite Advanced PDF Template, I got 00/01/2017, 0th moth, when I set date format to mm/dd/yyyy

Tags: oracle, freemarker, netsuite

I used <#setting date_format="mm/dd/yyyy"/> to set my date format. However, When I print the dates, it always print 00/xx/xxxx, 0th month.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`mm` means minutes, not months in year; use `MM` for that: `MM/dd/yyyy`. See: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html